# Two way databinding not updating with multiple components and a service

Tags: angular

I have an application with a "configurator" where people can select products from a list and filter that list with the needs they have. In this `configurator` component i have a `click` event which is handled as a function see my component below:

```
# configurator.component.ts

import {Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import {ProductService} from "./product.service";
import {Product} from "./product.model";
import {CurrencyPipe} from "@angular/common";
import {ShoppingcartService} from "../shoppingcart/shoppingcart.service";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'configurator',
    templateUrl: './configurator.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./configurator.component.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ProductService, ShoppingcartService],
    pipes: [CurrencyPipe]
})
export class ConfiguratorComponent implements OnInit {

    public products:Product[];

    constructor(private productService:ProductService, private shoppingcartService:ShoppingcartService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getProducts();
    }

    getProducts() {
        this.productService.getProducts().then(products => this.products = products);
    }

    addProduct(product:Product) {
        this.shoppingcartService.add(product);
    }
}
```

From here all looks ok and the service in `addProduct` is called as expected. The trigger at the service is executed and the array of shoppingcart products is growing with every single click. The service is handled like this:

```
# shoppingcart.service.ts

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Product} from "../configurator/product.model";

@Injectable()
export class ShoppingcartService {

    products:Product[];

    constructor() {
        this.products = [];
    }

    get() {
        return this.products;
    }

    add(product:Product) {
        this.products.push(product);
    }

    remove() {
        console.log('Remove not implemented yet');
    }

    clear() {
        this.products = [];
    }
}
```

The problem there is, is that the changes from the `add` call on the service are not reflecting on the application itself. I defined an `ngFor` at the template but it does not seem to pick it up:

```
# shoppingcart.component.html

<h2>Shoppingcart</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let product of products">
                {{product.name}}
                <span class="pull-right">{{product.maf | currency:'EUR':true:'1.2'}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the shoppingcart component itself:

```
# shoppingcart.component.ts

import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import {Product} from "../configurator/product.model";
import {CurrencyPipe} from "@angular/common";
import {ShoppingcartService} from "./shoppingcart.service";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'shoppingcart',
    templateUrl: './shoppingcart.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ShoppingcartService],
    pipes: [CurrencyPipe]
})

export class ShoppingcartComponent implements OnInit {

    products:Product[];

    constructor(private shoppingCartService:ShoppingcartService) {
        this.products = [];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.products = this.shoppingCartService.get();
    }
}
```

I hope it is something small since it seems that all data is there and it looks like only the binding is not going well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide `ShoppingcartService` on every component, every component will get it's own instance. If one component updates data in the service it's in a different instance than the service another component listens for changes.

Provide `ShoppingcartService` **only once** at a common parent component. If you want to share one instance with the whole application then this is the `AppComponent`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and i can do that. But how does that fit in my example? If i add it to the directives of the HomeComponent (which is laying on top of it where appComponent handles the pre-authentication stuff). How can the configurator component then communicate with this service?